# How to add hint into EditText with inputType="numberDecimal"?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `EditText` like below:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_sum"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:hint="Enter sum" />
```

But the hint is not displayed. Is it possible to display the `EditText` hint with `inputType="numberDecimal"` or not?

Comment: It seems unnecessary to me to use `android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"`. Is there any change if you remove that?

Answer (score 21):

you can use

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

to make the hint displayed with an inputtype and gravity

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be a problem with using `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`. Try removing that line as it made the hint appear for me.

Comment: Well, it was the issue, but when you want to center the text and focus the cursor in the center, then you got a problem.  here is the solution if that is the case.               android:ellipsize="start"
                android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of my EditText tags to compare with:

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/txtNumbText"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:hint="Number Hint Text">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi we can not use Gravity attribute and inputtype="number" attribute at a time so better to neglect gravity attribute.

if u want set hint in middle of edit text use like this : android:hint="    hint  "

give space in hint text

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/xEt" android:layout_width="170dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="   numbers only "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```